# Hi, How can i sum all elements in sqlite database together to get the sum total of the number using Flask(python)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

The model and view

from flask import Flask
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

```
    class account (db.Model):
         id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
         amount = db.Column(db.BigInteger,default=0)
         today=db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,  default=datetime.utcnow)



    @app.route('/office' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def office():
        funds = account.query.all()
        for fund in funds:
            print (fund.amount)
```

This code ran well without error listing all the amount in the database but if i should add sum to the second code it gives error

```
    * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production  deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://localhost:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 263-984-974
5247065
5247065
5247065
5247065
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:02:59] "GET /office HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I'm trying to add all the list together to get the sum total output.

```
@app.route('/office' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def office():
    funds = account.query.all()
    for fund in funds:
        print (sum(fund.amount))
```

it's giving error.

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://localhost:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 263-984-974
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:08:50] "GET /office HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/blazskills/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/blazskills/Documents/tacgwarimpalatest/app.py", line 205, in office
    print (sum(fund.amount))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:08:50] "GET /office?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:08:50] "GET /office?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:08:50] "GET /office?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:08:50] "GET /office?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 16:08:50] "GET /office?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
funds = account.query.all()
print(sum([fund.amount for fund in funds]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,
For example;

```
yourarray = [12, 3, 4, 15] 

ans = sum(your array)
```

And ensure the value you are passing to the sum function is structured properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go around this;

Sum them all in your python code (you're using this) or sum them at the database level (performance smart, you should use this)

**Method A.** using your approach:

```
@app.route('/office' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def office():
    accounts = account.query.all()
    funds = [account.fund for account in accounts] 
    total_fund = sum(funds)
```

**Method B.** to sum them at the database level, add this to your model class:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
def total_funds(self):
    return db.session.query(func.sum(account.amount))
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Really helpful